# Select last row of each unique combination in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to select last of row each unique combination, irrespective of the combination element order. For example combination `(5,6)` and `(6,5)` will be regarded as same combination.

Here is data on table:
[image]

**My expected output:**

[image]

**What I have done so far:**

```
Select * From
(
Select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (Partition by SenderId, ReceiverId order by MessageId desc) as Seq From Messages
) as TempTalbe Where Seq = 1
```

**And the output of my query is:**

[image]

Any help from SQL Server experts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` for this.  The traditional method is:

```
select m.*
from (select m.*,
             row_number() over (partition by (case when senderId < receiverId then senderId else receiverId end),
                                             (case when senderId < receiverId then receiverId else senderId end)
                                order by messageSentAt desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from messages m
     ) m
where seqnum = 1;
```

You can also phrase this without the subquery:

```
select top (1) with ties m.*
from messages m
order by row_number() over (partition by (case when senderId < receiverId then senderId else receiverId end),
                                         (case when senderId < receiverId then receiverId else senderId end)
                            order by messageSentAt desc
                           );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select messageId,
       messageBody,
       messageSentAt,
       isRead
from (
    select messageId,
           messageBody,
           messageSentAt,
           isRead,
           row_number() over (partition by senderId, receiverId order by messageSentAt desc) rn
    from (
        select messageId,
               case when senderId > receiverId then senderId else receiverId end senderId,
               case when senderId < receiverId then senderId else receiverId end receiverId,
               messageBody,
               messageSentAt,
               isRead
        from Messages
    ) a
) a where rn = 1
```

The most inner query unifies senders and receivers, so their order is irrelevant:

```
case when senderId > receiverId then senderId else receiverId end senderId,
case when senderId < receiverId then senderId else receiverId end receiverId,
```

The intermediate query assign row number to each row, so first is the latest date. Most outer query just filters based on that row number.

Comment: You have to valid answers. I am glad I could help :) You should accept answer which you like better, but the other works and was posted earlier, thus I think you should accept it, as you did :)